# How to plot a mekko chart in Excel?

Tags: excel, histogram, barplot

So a question you will have from here!

Q: What is Mekko?
A. Its like a histogram. The bar chart can show information in two axes. Normally in a bar chart the y axis shows the variation and x shows just categories/labels. Check [Mekko Graphics](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.mekkographics.com/&ei=He-lUMCxFsjJhAels4GwAw&usg=AFQjCNF6Wwkr-2Hkw2nka8PtvhOmOtXvSA&sig2=KeSzuq9exubO1obHxjm4KQ)

So my question is if there are any open source ways of getting these into Excel :)

Update: All the charts on [Types of Mekko Charts](http://www.mekkographics.com/learn/tools-to-help-you-chart/chart-finder/) but specifically the Bar-Mekko as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Looking at the Mekko website, they advertise "32 chart types". I guess you will need to be a little more specific as to which type exactly you want.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might try looking at [Jon Peltier's blog](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/). He does amazing things with Excel charts

Comment: These pages have templates as well as instructions: andypope.info/charts/colwidth.htm andypope.info/charts/colwidth2.htm

Answer (score 5):

Some people call this a cascade chart, but cascade chart means waterfall chart to other people. Check out this tutorial on my blog: [Variable Width Column Charts (Cascade Charts)](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/variable-width-column-charts/).

For a regular Marimekko chart, check this one: [Marimekko Charts](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/marimekko-charts/).

Comment: An answer from the man himself - Thanks! Will definitely have a look :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a fair bit of manual intervention if you repeat the y values x times.  So in your case you have a column of numbers that is 7 x 41, 6 x 51, 1 x30.  Draw a normal column chart, and change the gap between columns to zero.  Then you can use the "select data" editor to change the horizontal labels by pointing them to another aribtrary column - choosing mostly blanks.  You can also manually change the column colours if necessary.  What a bore though - lots of pointing and clicking.

Comment: Yeah we can but definitely can't afford the time :)!